# How to determine how many entries there are in a page table

Tags: operating-system, page-tables

Suppose my system is using a 32-bit address space with each entry being 32 bits and with each page being 8 KB. How many different entries would the page table contain?

My logic: 32-bit address space implies 2^32 total addresses, therefore 2^37 total bits. 8 KB per page implies 2^16 total bits per page. Therefore, there will be 2^37 / 2^16 = 2^21 entries in the page table.

Is this correct?

Comment: "2^32 total addresses, **therefore** 2^37 total bits" -- what is 'therefore"? You are overthinking the significance of 'bit' in modern computing. Sticking to *bytes*, it is as simple as 8KB/(sizeof(1 address-in-bytes)). (And I also get the same number when I do this "in bits".)

Comment: The number of page table entries is system specific. Factors effecting the number include the division of the address space and the number limits imposed by the system. Few system configurations give a process access to the full range of the virtual address space.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to consider the number of bits in a byte.  The answer to the general question is:

```
number of total addresses
-------------------------
number of bytes per page
```

So for your problem it is 2^32 / 2^13 = 2^19.